# Does grails / hibernate store Dates with milliseconds in PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, datetime, postgresql, grails

I'm currently using grails with classes storing java.util.Date fields als DATETIME. However I need the precision / milliseconds to be stored as well which I think is not possible with MySQL.

If I switch to PostgreSQL, will it store my Dates with millisecond precision (or is it easy to configure it this way)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Hibernate / PostgreSQL can also store milisecond precision, no problem. Use the Hibernate [timestamp](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Hibernate/JavaTypeVSHibernateType.htm) datatype.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since MySql 5.6.4 you can use 
   DATETIME(3) for milliseconds, or 
   DATETIME(6) for microseconds

TIME and other types also now support precision.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html